# mysql - How aright get count with left joing?

Tags: mysql

Structure tables on [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19)

if i use query:

```
SELECT 
    ei.ItemIdn as ItemIdn,
    ei.UserIdn as UserIdn

FROM items ei

WHERE ei.UserIdn = '0000' 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

I get 4 rows, but if i want get count viewers for each row:

```
SELECT 
    ei.ItemIdn as ItemIdn,
    ei.UserIdn as UserIdn,
    ifnull(count(cv.ItemIdn),0) as CountShow

FROM items ei

    left join CountViewes as cv on ei.ItemIdn = cv.ItemIdn

WHERE ei.UserIdn = '0000' 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

I get only one row.

Tell me please how get all rows and `count(cv.ItemIdn)` for each row?

Answer (score 1):

I do believe your query needs to end with GROUP BY because it contains an aggregate function.

```
GROUP BY ei.ItemIdn, ei.UserIdn
```

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19/32/0

Comment: Functions like `COUNT()`, `SUM()`, `MAX()`, and so forth have the purpose of summarizing the values in tables. As soon one of these functions shows up in a query it becomes a aggregate query -- that is a query to summarize the table's values. `GROUP BY` creates the groups of rows over which the summaries are generated. If you leave it out, that means the query is to summarize the entire table into a single row. Hence your one-row result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing the GROUP BY clause - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19/26

```
SELECT 
    ei.ItemIdn as ItemIdn,
    ei.UserIdn as UserIdn,
    COUNT(cv.ItemIdn) as CountShow
FROM items ei
LEFT JOIN CountViewes as cv on ei.ItemIdn = cv.ItemIdn
WHERE ei.UserIdn = '0000' 
GROUP BY ItemIdn, UserIdn
LIMIT 0, 25
```